# G++ doesn't permit use of protected default constructor in base class when both are templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, protected

I've created a [header for optionally-lazy parameters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/133991/110660) (also visible in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/tree/master/GenericCppCode/OptionalLaziness)).

In my original version of the code, I provided a protected default constructor for my base-class template:

```
template <typename VAL_TYPE>
class LazyType_Base
{
    // ....
    LazyType_Base(void) =default;
// ....
```

Then, in one of the derived classes:

```
template <typename VAL_TYPE>
class LazyType_Eager : public LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>
{
  public:
    LazyType_Eager(
        VAL_TYPE&& final_val)
      : LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>{}
      , val_{final_val}
    {}
// .....
```

This compiles just fine with Clang++, but in G++ 5.1, I get this error:

```
In file included from Test_OptionallyLazy.cpp:3:0:
OptionallyLazy.hpp: In instantiation of ‘LazyType_Eager<VAL_TYPE>::LazyType_Eager(VAL_TYPE&&) [with VAL_TYPE = int]’:
Test_OptionallyLazy.cpp:22:14:   required from here
OptionallyLazy.hpp:23:5: error: ‘LazyType_Base<VAL_TYPE>::LazyType_Base() [with VAL_TYPE = int]’ is protected
     LazyType_Base(void) =default;
     ^
OptionallyLazy.hpp:58:23: error: within this context
       , val_{final_val}
```

What's going on here? The weirdest bit is that the other derived class does something similar that *doesn't* trigger an error.

Replacing the `=default` constructor with the explicit default implementation `{}` resolves the compiler error.

**EDIT:** Thanks to T.C., [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J8sHbWHYFQ26hHZq) is a real MCVE:

```
class Meow
{
  protected:
    Meow(void) =default;    
  public:    
    virtual void f() {}
};

class Purr : public Meow
{
  public:
    Purr()
      : Meow{}
    {}

};
```

Comment: @WhiZTiM I've got one set up (it's basically just the two files in the linked GitHub, concatenated). How do I save the session with a permalink?

Comment: @WhiZTiM Ah, found it. Added a link.

Comment: Minimized: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J8sHbWHYFQ26hHZq

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71774

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the minimization (looks like all I was missing was the `virtual` function on `Base`?) and the bug report!

Comment: Heh. My first question here was about one of the various problems GCC has where brace-construction of class members breaks access control. I still have to use parentheses in various places. I've also run into some other issues where braces cause segfaults(?!?!) but haven't been able to minimise them down yet as they seem dependent on inheritance from library classes.