# Virtual destructor alters behavior of decltype

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, decltype, virtual-destructor

I've created a [header for optionally-lazy parameters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/133991/110660) (also visible in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/PublicPaste/tree/master/GenericCppCode/OptionalLaziness)). (This is [not my first question based on the header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213809/1858225).)

I have a base-class template and two derived-class templates. The base-class template has a `protected` constructor with a `static_assert`. This constructor is only called by a particular derived-class. Inside of the `static_assert` I'm using a `decltype`.

The really bizarre thing is that the type of *a name inside the `decltype`* is somehow affected by the whether or not there is a virtual destructor in my base-class template.

Here's my MCVE:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class Base
{
  protected:
    template <typename U>
    Base(U&& callable)
    {
      static_assert(
          std::is_same<
              typename std::remove_reference<decltype(callable())>::type, T
            >::value,
          "Expression does not evaluate to correct type!");
    }

  public:
    virtual ~Base(void) =default; // Causes error 

    virtual operator T(void) =0;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
  public:
    Derived(U&& callable) : Base<T>{std::forward<U>(callable)} {}

    operator T(void) override final
    {
      return {};
    }
};

void TakesWrappedInt(Base<int>&&) {}

template <typename U>
auto MakeLazyInt(U&& callable)
{
  return Derived<
            typename std::remove_reference<decltype(callable())>::type, U>{
      std::forward<U>(callable)};
}

int main()
{
  TakesWrappedInt(MakeLazyInt([&](){return 3;}));
}
```

Note that if the destructor is commented out, this compiles without error.

The intent is for `callable` to be an expression of type `U` that, when called with the `()` operator, returns something of type `T`. Without the virtual destructor in `Base`, it appears that this is evaluated correctly; *with* the virtual destructor, it appears that `callabele`'s type is `Base<T>` (which, as far as I can tell, makes no sense).

Here's G++ 5.1's error message:

```
recursive_lazy.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Base<T>::Base(U&&) [with U = Base<int>; T = int]’:
recursive_lazy.cpp:25:7:   required from ‘auto MakeLazyInt(U&&) [with U = main()::<lambda()>]’
recursive_lazy.cpp:48:47:   required from here
recursive_lazy.cpp:13:63: error: no match for call to ‘(Base<int>) ()’
               typename std::remove_reference<decltype(callable())>::type, T
```

Here's Clang++ 3.7's error message:

```
recursive_lazy.cpp:13:55: error: type 'Base<int>' does not provide a call operator
              typename std::remove_reference<decltype(callable())>::type, T
                                                      ^~~~~~~~
recursive_lazy.cpp:25:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'Base<int>::Base<Base<int> >' requested here
class Derived : public Base<T>
      ^
1 error generated.
```

[Here is an online version.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sMIPy6lEX1jQFkjZ)

**EDIT:** `=delete`-ing the copy-constructor *also* triggers this error.

Comment: I couldn't tell you about the weird virtual destructor error, but I see that `Derived(U&& callable)` takes an r-value reference and not a universal reference.  Is that intended?

Comment: Could you add some ouput to the example showing what it's supposed to do. TakesWrappedInt seems to get a zero with your example, due to the final operator T();.

Comment: @GuyGreer No, it is not intended. Is that because once the template is specialized, U is no longer a template type?

Comment: @JohanLundberg That's correct; this is just an MCVE, and the value of the integer isn't part of the problem. For a more complete context, click on the links in the first sentence.

Comment: @GuyGreer ....though really, with the intended usage, `callable` probably *should* be an r-value reference.

Comment: It's because once the class' templates are determined they are no longer deduced for the functions (which makes sense, you couldn't have different definitions of `U` in different parts of the same class).

Comment: @GuyGreer Yes, sorry, by "no longer a template type" I meant "no longer deduced" (I now realize my previous comment wasn't using the right terminology).

Comment: ...in other words, this has nothing to do with `virtual` and everything to do with a greedy unconstrained constructor that accepts everything under the sun.

Comment: @T.C. Maybe there's some magic using `enable_if` I could use to constrain it? Oddly enough (to me, at least), making the constructors `explicit` does not help (I get the same error). Frankly, I feel like the "constructor from universal reference" feature of C++ is simply too hard to use correctly for my comfort.

Comment: ....I suppose if `explicit` fixed the issue in this case, then return-by-value would be be broken in many surprising ways....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that when you declare destructor, implicit move constructor won't be declared, because

(N4594 12.8/9)

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly
>   declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> ...
>
> - **X does not have a user-declared destructor**

`Base` has user-declared destructor (it doesn't matter that it's defaulted).

When `MakeLazyInt` tries to return constructed `Derived` object,  it calls `Derived` move constructor.

`Derived` implicitly-declared move constructor doesn't call `Base` move constructor (because that doesn't exist), but rather your templated `Base(U&&)` constructor.

And here's the problem, `callable` parameter doesn't contain *callable* object but `Base` object, which really doesn't contain `operator ()`.

To solve the problem simply declare move constructor inside `Base`:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
  protected:
    template <typename U>
    Base(U&& callable)
    {
      static_assert(
          std::is_same<
              typename std::remove_reference<decltype(callable())>::type, T
            >::value,
          "Expression does not evaluate to correct type!");
    }

  public:
    virtual ~Base(void) =default; // When declared, no implicitly-declared move constructor is created

    Base(Base&&){} //so we defined it ourselves

    virtual operator T(void) =0;
};
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. I know that rule but didn't see how it applied, based on the error message. Thank you. Do you know if C++17's guaranteed copy-ellision would have avoided this problem?

Comment: @KyleStrand Well based on second rule *In a function call, if the operand of a return statement is a prvalue and the return type of the function is the same as the type of that prvalue.*, I think compiler will elide move constructor, but I'm not sure why compiler didn't elided it in this case.

Comment: @PcAF Copy-ellision is an optimization, so the compiler may consider it an error even if the copy *will* be elided to have a construct that would fail if the copy were *not* elided. This is why I suspect that guaranteed copy-elision may resolve the issue.

Comment: @KyleStrand You're right. I've [tested](http://ideone.com/jdu5f7) it, and it seems that compiler optimized it away. I think guaranteed copy-elision will resolve the issue: *In those cases **where copy-elision is not guaranteed**, if it takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, **it must be present and accessible** (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.* [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)